# Angular 5 Template Extension

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-template

I have been trying to implement a solution for this for a while and I have not come to a clean one yet.

Please, help me.

I have 2 routes:

1. /login
2. /register

They have very similar templates:

login.html

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <section class="fullwidth-split">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          [...more similar html to both views...]
          <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
        <div class="col-12">
            Login form HTML
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

register.html

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <section class="fullwidth-split">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          [...more similar html to both views...]
          <h2>Registration</h2>
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
        <div class="col-12">
            Registration form HTML
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

As you can see, most of the HTML is the same, including the section and container div. I would like to reuse this template and I have tried using child routes and using  on the dynamic HTML part, but as you can see the h2 changes its content as well, so unless I duplicate this template it's not possible. The best I've got is using the router-outlet, but then I have a STATIC title h2 and can't change it on the child component because it's on the parent component template.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your child templates have their own controllers you can set a value on the parent scope with `scope.page=""` then when you navigate to the login section, update the value of page from login controller using `$scope.$parent.page = "Login";` and do the same in the controller for registration and use `<h2>{{page}}</h2>` in your parent template.

Comment: Please never tag a question with angular and with angularjs. Look at the comment above, it's not applicable but your tag confused a user and they wasted their time

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry, can you help me though?

Comment: @GabrielVeloso no problem, just letting you know for the future. Sorry I don't know what the deal is here, I just fixed the tags in passing. Good luck.

Comment: You probably need to add your router configuration to the question for anyone to be able to help you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution.
Create a component (my-component) that uses the shared html and add content projection to it. The html should look something like this:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

You project the different content like this:

register.html:

```
<my-component>
  <h2> Registration </h2>
</my-component>
```

login.html:

```
<my-component>
  <h2> Login </h2>
</my-component>
```

You could also have multiple content projections.
This is done by adding a select attribute to the ng-content in my-component:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <ng-content select=".heading-content"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select=".form-content"></ng-content>
</div>
```

And use like this:

```
<my-component>
  <h2 class="heading-content"> Login </h2>
  <div class="form-content">
    .....
  </div>
</my-component>
```